# How to replace ../../ with d:/ in my ajax response in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to replace the `../../` in ajax response with `D:/` using JavaScript.

Actually I want to replace the image `src` attr having relative path `../../` with absolute path in my html.

Comment: string.replace('../../', 'd:/') - no need for regex

Comment: Can you share what have you tried and achieved yet?

Comment: str.replace(/..\/..\//g,"d:/");

Comment: Actually I want to replace the image src attr having relative path ../../ with absolute path in my html

Comment: regex `/\.\.\/\.\.\//g`

Comment: Why you want to use file paths in a web app? Can we see the AJAX code you have presently?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
str = '../../dsadsddad'
var new_str = str.replace('../../', 'D:/')

// new_str = "D:/dsadsddad"
```

if you want change `src` attrubute in your image, try this:

```
var image = document.getElementById("your_image_id").
image.src = image.getAttribute('src').replace('../../', 'D:/')
```